# Why is 0 < -0.75 < 1 true?

Tags: javascript, logic, ternary-operator

In the case of a variable being inside a range, does JS only evaluate the last conditional;`-0.75 < 1` and not the first; `0 < -0.75`?

Comment: You should use 0 < -0.75 && -0.75 < 1.

Comment: thats not a ternary evaluation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 < -0.75 => false(0)

0 < 1 => true

You should use 0 < -0.75 && -0.75 < 1